# storing dates from a text file into an array

Tags: java

In my java program I have a text file of dates and im trying to store each into an array. However the day, month and year keep getting stored into a different part of the array and not together please help me. These are a few of the lines from the text file

12/12/1996,23/08/2000,27/02/1980

12/04/1976, 24/09/2003, 13/06/1993

30/07/1995, 20/06/2004, 23/05/1990

```
private static String person1Date[];

private static String person2Date[];

private static String person3Date[];
static int count =0;

person1Date = new String[100];
person2Date = new String[100];
person3Date = new String[100];

File dateFiles = new File(dates.txt);

Scanner dates = new Scanner(dateFiles);

while(dates.hasNextLine)
{
String datesLine = dates.nextLine();
String [] datesDetails = datesLine.split(",");
 person1Date[count] = datesDetails[0].trim();
 person2Date[count] = datesDetails[1].trim();
 person3Date[count] = datesDetails[2].trim();
 count++;
}
```

Comment: It is working as expected. Can you explain what you want it to do more precisely?

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized the variable count used to set the position of the array where you want to store the dates. Write :

```
int count = 0;
```

before the loop and you're done.

Comment: I did do that i just forgot to put that on here cause like the day has been saying in person1Date, month in person2Date and year in person3Date and I don't know why

Comment: Wait a minute, what are you scanning, dates or dateFiles? I think the problem might come from there. Try changin String datesLine = dates.nextLine(); to String datesLine = dateFiles.nextLine();

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Its still spliting the day, month and year when it should only split at a comma